# Updating a production database with SQL encryption - mass update shortcuts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2012

I am trying to encrypt a lot of columns in a lot of tables. I have a basic understanding of how to encrypt and decrypt using keys and certificates, but not how I can implement this on a large scale.

For example, I have a few columns in a table with sql code on our production apps to select to insert or update. Would I need to go back to revise each and every sql query to include a ENCRYPTBYKEY() and DECRYPTBYKEY() method in these queries? Are there any solutions or shortcuts to update a production server to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you would need to update all writes to use `encryptbykey` and all reads to use `decryptbykey`

If you are using stored procedures or have CRUD operations centralized and locked down, this can make things easier - but it is still a time consuming process.  Another option is [Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) which can be applied to an entire database w/o changing code; though there are still several commands that need to be run on the server.

Comment: Looking into TDE seems to be an excellent solution for saving us implementation time, but instead of doing just a few columns of encryption, it encrypts the entire database. Wouldn't this increase query execution times by like double PER every column in the query you're trying to interact with?

Comment: from http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/transparent-data-encryption-faqs > Yes, some performance overhead is involved in using TDE. The encryption and decryption process do require additional CPU cycles. The overhead for using TDE ranges from about 3 percent to 30 percent, depending on the type of workload.

SQL Server instances with low I/O and low CPU usage will have the least performance impact. Servers with high CPU usage will have the most performance impact.

Comment: also note, in case you haven't happened upon the information yet - as far as I'm aware TDE requires enterprise edition of sql-server (for sure the case for 2008-2012, have not worked with later versions but assuming the same applies)

Comment: You saved me and the our dev team a month of work. Thanks!

Comment: @Jayizzle right?  And depending on the size of your team, that might make up for the cost of the enterprise licences if you don't already have them :P